# I've gone visited

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

I am watching John Krasinski's interview and he is asked if he can speak Polish. His answer is: "I can speak Polish words that are related to food. I should learn. I've gone visited Poland and had the best time ever". What does the construction "have + V3 + V3" mean in this context? Is it gramatically correct? Never seen it before.

Or he just interrupted his thought and corrected himself by instantly replacing "gone" with "visited"?

Timing is 5:15

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guRbfQFddfg&t=5m14s

Comment: Looks like a transcription error. Either Krasinski said "I've gone ***and*** visited ..." or there was a pause in his statement to choose a different verb: "I've gone ... visited Poland and had the best time ever." And having watched the video now, I can tell you that it looks like the latter.

Comment: @Robusto that is what I thought as well. But he said it so confidently, no pause. So I wanted to make it clear. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a mishearing of spoken English rather than a matter of English language or usage.

Comment: There’s a clear pause, which I would transcribe as “I’ve gone, visited Poland”. It’s tricky how to render real dialogue where the speaker changes track mid-sentence. Instead of a comma, an em dash or ellipsis marks (“...”) would also work. It’s a matter of style.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Re 'There’s a clear pause, which I would transcribe as “I’ve gone, visited Poland”.' Is separating two verbs like there with a comma acceptable only in transcription of dialogue, or in other contexts too (fiction, non-fiction writing, etc.)?

Comment: @Robusto It sounds like "I've gone 'n' visited Poland" to me. He definitely doesn't say the "a" or "d" in "and". Since "gone" ends in /n/, the second /n/ is almost swallowed up. Compare it with "if you haven't gone" where the /n/ is noticeably shorter.

Comment: Yeah, but really swallowing the *'n'* ...

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed *"Is separating two verbs like there with a comma acceptable only in transcription...?"* As I noted in my earlier comment, the use of commas, dashes or other punctuation is **a matter of style**. A *style guide* sets out what is "acceptable", so the question should therefore be: "Is this piece of writing required to follow a particular style guide?" In the absence of a prescribed style guide (or a publishing house editor's personal preference), the comma would be "acceptable" in any context and would be "correct" if it conveys to the reader the intended meaning.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica I didn't mean *acceptable* for contexts where the piece of writing is required to abide by a particular style guide (though it would be interesting to know, too, whether some style guides have any rules for the usage in question). By *acceptable* I meant "in reasonably common use" in any contexts e.g. fiction or any type of non-fiction writing; I can't recall having seen a comma used for this purpose so I wanted to know whether it is at least reasonably common. So whether or not the comma is *acceptable* in the sense that it conveys the intended meaning ...

Comment: ... to the readers is tangential to my inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen again. He says, "I've gone *and* visited Poland and had the best time ever."

If you listen more closely, you'll hear the *and*. That's standard conversational English.

Comment: I have listened to it about 20 times and am still not being able to hear "and". He slurred it a lot. Anyway, thank you for help!

Comment: It is quiet and very clipped, but I hear, "I've gone-en-visited Poland"

Comment: A syllabic nasal following a homophonous non-syllabic nasal is a matter of length of the nasal. Which is not something that can be talked about reasonably without millisecond timing data.

Comment: The word isn't "en." That wouldn't make sense. He's saying "and" in ordinary coversational American English. I heard it the first time I listened. But I'm an American listening to an American. So for me it's easy.

Comment: @CharlieBernstein He pronounces "and" as /n/. He doesn't pronounce the "a" or "d" in "and".